# please tell me why 1 of these 2 identical URL's get's picked up by FB graph, while the other does not?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have 2 nearly identical links that both have the appropriate facebook open graph meta tags.  However, 1 of them does NOT get picked up by Facebook and the other one does:

WORKS
http://sephora.com/browse/product.jhtml?id=P53162&categoryId=B65

BROKEN
http://sephora.com/browse/product.jhtml?id=P276328&categoryId=B15

My test for what works, versus what is broken is when I "like" the page, the object/URL should appear on my "likes" list whenever I visit graph.facebook.com/me/likes.  the FIRST url is correctly seen on my likes list, however the SECOND does not even get added.

Any ideas why? they are nearly identical URL's.

I have already put both through http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ but had no luck.  Please let help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, The URL you have in your OG tag is different from the URL entered:  see

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fsephora.com%2Fbrowse%2Fproduct.jhtml%3Fid%3DP53162%26categoryId%3DB65

http://sephora.com/browse/product.jhtml?id=P53162&categoryId=B65

vs

http://www.sephora.com/browse/product.jhtml?id=P53162

Notice the www. in front of the second one as well as the missing categoryId from the querystring.

Answer (score 0):

both work for me
liked, fetched open graph, added to wall